# How to unsubscribe from Camel JMS durable subscription

Tags: apache-camel, jms, durable-subscription

[The Camel documentation](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.20.x/eips/durable-subscriber.html) shows how to subscribe to a (non-)shared durable subscription, but what about unsubscribing?

Using AzureServiceBus it is not possible to set auto delete on idle for subscription and we can't use this for topics unless we open up permissions to the app, which we are trying to avoid.

Component dsl was used to configure the JMS component

I've tried creating a `jmsContext` from using same connection factory, clientId and durable subscription name in another method, but it claims the subscription no longer exists.